# Can you explain parameters between func keyword and function name?

Tags: function, go

I'm new to the language and so far what I have read doesn't explain what is happening here.

I was looking at [JSON decoding](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder).

Here is a function in the package:

```
func (dec *Decoder) Decode(v interface{}) error
```

There is similar notation here:

```
func (dec *Decoder) Buffered() io.Reader
```

How do these functions access the `(dec *Decoder)`? Given that the second function has no parameters, I am guessing this is not something that must be passed directly in the function call but something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two functions are [methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) because they are associated with receivers. In each method declaration, `(dec *Decoder)` describes the receiver. If you have a `*Decoder` called `decoder`, you call `Buffered` on it like this:

```
reader := decoder.Buffered()
```

Take a look at the [the Go tutorial lesson](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1) on this topic.